# I can't install Memgraph Platform via Docker - "docker unauthorize authentication required"

Tags: memgraphdb

I can't install Memgraph Platform via Docker. I keep getting the error message "`docker unauthorize authentication required`".

It all works for Memgraph image:

```
newus@song-wks:~# docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 --name memgraph memgraph/memgraph
Unable to find image 'memgraph/memgraph¡latest' locally
latest: Pulling from memgraph/memgraph
2f088d622efd: Pull complete
f53f9bd66fc3: Pull complete
C0e75b7781e7: Pull complete
489cd6275771: Pull complete
4737ee95d849: Pull complete
4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete
Digest : sha256:3f5f2ac082ef26cf52ab2dcabd91beeca432de2b0224f7a3dc50e397c7b2e8e8 Status: Downloaded newer image for memgraph/memgraph:latest You are running Memgraph V2.12.1
To get started with Memgraph, visit https://memgr.ph/start
```

But not for Memgraph Platform:

```
newus@song-wks:~# docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 --name memgraph memgraph/memgraph-platform:latest

Unable to find image 'memgraph/memgraph-platform:latest' locally latest: Pulling from memgraph/memgraph-platform dlda99c2fl48: 
Pull complete 3bfd201ccbe3: Extracting [==> ]   11.14MB/262.7MB
7bbf5c5d6fld: Download complete 
db2413e75880: Download complete 
2bdebd490492: Download complete 
72el723eb8c3: Download complete 
2fd818cdl4c9: Download complete 
35cbdbc942c7: Download complete 
503a2dbe39f2: Download complete 
d00638a09bdl: Downloading [====> ]  87.88MB/982.4MB
01eadfae4280: Download complete 
7df3818bc0d9: Download complete 
38705fe31799: Download complete 
69d6240e3dc3: Download complete 
e73adb9fe671: Download complete 
3a32al99619a: Download complete 
3721315858cd: Downloading [=================> ] 4.33MB/12.4MB
4f4fb700ef54: Downloading
docker: unauthorized: authentication required.
See 'docker run --help'. newus@song-wks:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue in the following way:

- Run `docker system prune`
- Logged out from Docker: `docker logout`
- Restarted the computer: `sudo shutdown -r now`
- Logged in to Docker: `docker login`
- Pulled Memgraph Platform image: `docker pull memgraph/memgraph-platform`

I think that the problem was some cache or a partially pulled Docker image that caused the problem.